# Consume Wep Api with Header Parameter

Tags: jquery, header, postman, webapi, http-status-code-401

I wrote web api and consume it with postman succesfully, in header there is variable and its value.
Parameter name is ApiKey and i loaded value in the postman, So web api return answer succesfully.
But I could not consume with jquery,
It returns 401 code. I tryed bottom code but it is not worked.

```
$.ajax({
    url : 'http://XXX:8020/getPer/1010',
    dataType : "jsonp",
    headers: { "Content-Type":"application/json","Accept": "application/json" },
    type : 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    beforeSend : function( xhr ) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader( "ApiKey", "xxxyyyzzz" );
    },
    success : function (data) {
      console.log(data);
    },
    error : function (data, errorThrown) {
      alert(3);
    }
});
```

I put postman result also in bottom.

[SuccesfullyReturnedFromPostman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n4DDk.png)

Comment: 1) Are you sure the key you're using is identical in both cases. 2) You're returning JSON in the postman screenshot, yet you've set JSONP in the AJAX request - are you trying to work around CORS issues? If so, that's not going to work.

Comment: I am sure keys are same, but i will try to control CORS issues.

Answer (score 0):

Postman has support to generate code for multiple languages.

check here

[Dothttp](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ShivaPrasanth.dothttp-code) also has similar option and works well with developers.

Thanks